# What are the <value> of tox --parallel command?

Tags: unit-testing, tox

In this part of the documentation https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#cmdoption-tox-p the values are written `all` `auto` and `missing argument`
I am not clear about the missing argument values. Is this limited to cpu counts?

Basically, I am trying to limit the log of the command by removing the warning messages and maybe either just showing the passed message or just the error messages.

Using the `all` command it seems that all the messages has been hidden. It works same for the `auto` command as well. But if there is any error, it just shows all the logs for `auto` command.

So, I was wondering if there are other attributes that I can try for reaching what I intend to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding.

The `parallel` option, short also `-p`, is all about running several `tox` environments in parallel, e.g. when you test your app against py36, py37, py38, py39 (via entry in `envlist`, and when you have have 4 CPUs, you can use `tox -p` or `tox -p auto` or `tox -p 4` to run all jobs in parallel.

On the other hand, with just `tox` or with `tox -p 0` you run the jobs in sequence.

As a necessary side effect of running jobs in parallel, the output to the terminal needs to be adapted. It is no longer possible to just print each message (e.g. failure report) at any time, otherwise the output of the parallel jobs would get mixed up.

In our documentation, we also have a more detailed description of the `parallel` mode:

https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html?highlight=parallel#parallel-mode

Comment: I misunderstood. My bad. Thanks for clearing this out. 
For printing each message(e.g. failure report) is there any recommended approach? 
I tried before to remove the warning messages as well, but I only found out that I have to modify to the library level for doing that. TIA.

Comment: Could you give us an example of a message which you do not want to see? Usually it is a very good idea to see all failures and warnings. And please name the tool which output you want to modify. eg pytest has quite some options to change the output

Comment: Yes sure. Maybe only the last part `======
Totals
======
Ran: 799 tests in 7.4125 sec.
 - Passed: 796
 - Skipped: 3
 - Expected Fail: 0
 - Unexpected Success: 0
 - Failed: 0
Sum of execute time for each test: 33.5881 sec`

Comment: You still have not answered my question which tool you use to run tests, but I assume that is pytest. Please have a look at the pytest documenation, there are ways to configure the output, ie more verbose or more succint. About the deprecation warning: Usually, it is a very bad idea to ignore or even hide deprecation warnings, as at one point, they will turn into an error. Either fix the deprecation warning yourself, or when it is in a library, report it there and try to get it fixed. That is just my opinion :-)

Comment: I am using pytest. You guessed it right.
Yeah, initially that was my plan to solve the warning messages. 
In the `tox.ini` file if I change the value of the `OS_STDERR_CAPTURE` the warning messages goes away for now. 
Thanks for being patient and explaining small silly questions of mine(I am new to this).